# Place DIV or SPAN class inside stock available

Tags: magento2.3, css, xml, phtml

How can I place a div or span class inside stock available with custom xml. Would like custom block next to INSTOCK.

```
<body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.stock.sku">
            <block class="Stock\Qty\Block\LeftQty" name="catalog.product.view.stock"
                   before="product.info.stock.sku" template="Dolphin_MyModule::leftqty.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
```

[image: Product view]

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code, this will work:

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.stock.sku">
         <block class="Stock\Qty\Block\LeftQty" name="catalog.product.view.stock"before="product.info.sku" template="Dolphin_MyModule::leftqty.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Please let me know if you face any issue

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already created a custom module (let's call it "Dolphin_MyModule"), and you want to add a block next to the stock information:

1. Create a Block Class:

   In your custom module (Dolphin_MyModule), create a block class. This class will render the content you want to display next to the stock information. For example, you might create a block class named Dolphin\MyModule\Block\CustomBlock.
2. Create a Template File:

   In your module, create a template file (e.g., leftqtycustom.phtml) that contains the HTML structure you want to display next to the stock information.
3. Update Layout XML:
   Modify your layout XML file to include your custom block. You can add it after the product.info.stock.sku block

   ```
      <body>
       <referenceBlock name="product.info.stock.sku">
         <block class="Stock\Qty\Block\LeftQty" name="catalog.product.view.stock"
              before="product.info.stock.sku" template="Dolphin_MyModule::leftqty.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
      </referenceBlock>

      <referenceBlock name="product.info.stock.sku">
       <block class="Dolphin\MyModule\Block\CustomBlock" name="catalog.product.view.customblock"
              after="product.info.stock.sku" template="Dolphin_MyModule::leftqtycustom.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
     </referenceBlock>
     </body>
   ```
4. Flush Cache: